# Can vector components be in turn decomposed?

Tags: vectors

I've a basic (and maybe obvious even if I don't see it) question on the decomposition of a vector in physics.

An example of situation I'm confused about is the inclined plane with an object on it. There is only the weight force acting on it. Weight is vertical but it is usually decomposed in parallel and normal components to the inclined plane.

Referring to the first picture (on the left) the blue vector is wheight and the red ones are its decomposition. My question is about what I did in the second picture on the right. There I considered only one of the components of weight (the red normal one) and I decomposed it in vertical and orizontal components (the green ones). The question is: does this make any kind of sense or is it a total absurdity?

[image]

It seems impossible to me for a vertical vector to end up to have an horizontal component, perpendicular to it. Nevertheless in some situations I ended up with this doubt, that I cannot solve by myself.

Am I missing something important here?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible and not 'absurd'. But you're not doing it really right. Here's your force diagram again but with numbered forces:

[image: Forces decomposition.]

You decomposed $1$ correctly into $2$ and $3$. So forget about $1$ as it's now represented by $2$ and $3$.

Then you decomposed $2$ correctly into $4$ and $5$, so again forget about $2$ as it's represented by $4$ and $5$.

The vector sum of $3$, $4$ and $5$ is now effectively $1$.

Comment: Yes, but I took the intention of the OP to be the 5 would represent weight.  Mathematically you can do as you say, but 5 would have no physical significance.

Comment: In the first line after the picture I think you meant to say "forget about 1"?

Comment: @DavidZ: yes, muchas gracias. Corrected now.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are missing something. When you decompose a vector that represents a physical quantity, the physical quantity itself has to be represented by the hypotenuse of a right triangle.  The vector sum of the components (legs) must add to be a real quantity.  In your second diagram, the real quantity (green, down) is added to *something*  (which you rightly question) to give a vector (red) that seems to have a greater magnitude than the vector that represents the real quantity.   If gravity is the source of the force, how can you end up with a force *greater* than the source (gravity)?   No.  The second picture is incorrect.